# Problems with javac

Tags: windows, cmd, javac

[EDIT][EDIT2][EDIT3]I need help as I am starting on JSP. My goal is to run the java compiler in the windows cmd and I have encounter this error:

'javac' is not recognised as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

What I have done to debug this problem so far:(Not in order)

Check the path name
redownload the sdk
rerun the cmd after changing to the correct path name
Edited the environment variable to include the sdk

And yet all fails what have I not done correctly.

My pathname is It still doesn't work. I am following instructions from here   http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/tomcat_howto.html

This is my pathname: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`

For ricovox: This is the complete cmd output for path

`C:\Users\Zi>path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracl
e\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel
\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS
\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bi
n\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel
\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Manag
ement Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Eng
ine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Compo
nents\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\system32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110
\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Prog
ram Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQ
L Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL S
erver\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skyp
e\Phone\`

Edit System Variable
Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`
Variable value: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`

Comment: Which environment variable?

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to the instructions you are using. On which step do you get the 'javac' error?

Comment: Are you getting the error after typing `startup` from the Tomcat bin folder? Or is there another command where you are typing `javac` directly?

Comment: I am getting this error before typing startup

The error comes from here
`> cd \myProject\tomcat\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\classes   // change directory to the source file`
`> javac -cp .;d:\myProject\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar HelloServlet.java   // Compile`

Comment: Can you please do:  (1) Paste the full value of the "Variable Value" box on the Envronment Variables screen? *(which you edited to add the path)* and (2) Save and close the Environment Variables screen and then restart your PC. When you login, re-check the value and test it in a **new** command prompt.

Comment: Another way to go about this, if you cannot seem to get the PATH variable set from the Control Panel is to simply set it from the command-line or from a batch file. I.e. `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`    Then try to run javac, It should work with no problem.

Comment: When I said "Paste the full value..." I meant for the **Path** variable. I.e. Variable name: **Path**  Variable value: **C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation.....;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin**  (NOT from the command-line, but from the Environment Variables screen where you entered it.)

Comment: Thank you ricovox! Done! Finally! Many thanks! It seems I cant set the path variable using the GUI method.

Answer (score 0):

So first, please verify that you have set the **JAVA_HOME** environment variable. Here are the instructions to set it:

1. Open the Windows Control Panel Go to System ⇒ Advanced system
   settings
2. Switch to "Advanced" tab ⇒ Environment Variables
3. In the System Variables box, (**not** User variables), click "New" (or
   "Edit" for modification)
4. In "Variable Name", enter "JAVA_HOME"
5. In "Variable Value", enter your JDK installed directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`.
6. Click OK and close that window.

Now, open up a **NEW** windows command prompt (cmd.exe) and type the following:
`set JAVA_HOME`

You should see something like this:
`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`

Setting JAVA_HOME may be required for Tomcat/JSP, but just doing that will **not** necessarily allow you to run `javac` from the command-line. If you want to be able to do that, you also have to add the java bin folder to your PATH environment variable.

To do that, follow the same instructions as above, with some minor changes as shown below:

1. Open the Windows Control Panel Go to System ⇒ Advanced system
   settings
2. Switch to "Advanced" tab ⇒ Environment Variables
3. In the System Variables box, (**not** User variables), find the **Path** variable in the list and click on it. Then click the "Edit" button.
4. Copy the entire value in the "Variable Value" field and save it somewhere (just in case you make a mistake and need to restore it later.)
5. Press the END key to go to the end of the current **Path** value, then enter a semicolon (;) followed by your java directory. For example:
   `C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;...SomeOtherFolders...;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`
6. Click OK and close that window.

Now, open up a **NEW** windows command prompt (cmd.exe) and type the following:
`PATH`

You should see a list of paths and the list should contain your java directory (it may or may not be the last path in the list, depending on whether you have a Path variable defined in the User variables section.)

Once you have the java bin folder in your PATH, you should be able to run `javac` from the command-line.

You can test this by opening a command prompt and typing `javac -version`  You should see the output `javac 1.8.0_60`

You should also try `%JAVA_HOME%\javac -version` just to make sure your JAVA_HOME variable is correct.

I hope that helps.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am following instructions from here   http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/tomcat_howto.html 

This is my pathname: `code  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`

And this is the system variable that I have set:
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin

Comment: Correction the pathname is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`

Comment: Thanks for the promptly reply! Strange things happening with my computer.  
I have copied and paste the entire directory involving the sdk which is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin'  and edited the environement variables to this path.

And yet when I restart the cmd and I typed Path in the cmd the java bin is nowhere to be found

Comment: OK, since the problem occurs when you run 'javac', it means this has nothing to do with the JAVA_HOME variable, so just ignore that one for now. We need to focus on getting the PATH variable to include the path to the JDK.

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the "System variables" (not the "User variables") in the **Environment Variables** page of the Control Panel => System Properties => Advanced window?

Comment: Once you have made the change to the `Environment Variables` window and you click OK to close it, can you then re-open it and verify that your changes have persisted? If so, but it still doesn't show up in the command window when you type `PATH`, then perhaps try to restart your computer.

Comment: How I wish I can show u screen shots. I have restart my computer and ensure that I have made changes to the environment variables. I have ensure that I modified the system variable and not the user variable in system properties => advanced window. The path is still not showing up the java bin.